# how to switch to another screen while AdMob ads are displayed

Tags: swift, xcode, admob

I'm trying to show another viewcontroller after the ad has finished showing, but it turns out that after the ad, you have to click on the button again to go.

```
@IBAction func doSomething(_ sender: Any) {

        let save = UserDefaults.standard
        if save.value(forKey: "Purchased") == nil {
            if interstitial != nil {
                interstitial!.present(fromRootViewController: self)
            } else {
                print("Ad wasn't ready")
            }
        }else{
            print("PAID ADS OFF")
        }
    }

@IBAction func openExamSimulator(_ sender: Any) {
        let examVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExamSimulator") as! ExamSimulatorViewController
        doSomething((Any).self)
        examVC.status = "ExamSimulator"
        examVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(examVC, animated: true)
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue like this - added func adDidDismissFullScreenContent and delegate in to load ad

```
func loadInterstitial() {
        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ID")
        interstitial.load(request)
        interstitial.fullScreenContentDelegate = self //added delegate 
    } 

func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
          let examVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExamSimulator") as! ExamSimulatorViewController
          examVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
          present(examVC, animated: true)
          
      }
```